# training custom object in YOLOv3, how does it work?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, darknet, yolo

I got an project needs to detect person in anime-like style vedios

I just tested YOLOv3 608x608 with COCO in GTX 1050TI

however speed is only at about ~1.5FPS , but I need at least 10 FPS on 1050TI for my project

1.I want to know that does the number of the classes will effect detection speed?  (I assume COCO is about finding 80 kinds object in picture? if I just need find one kind of object, will it go 80x faster?)

2.when I input image for training ,original image are 1920*1080, should I resize them to 608x608 before labeling and training?

3.is there any labeling tool should I use?  in README.md at https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet `<x> <y> <width> <height>` seems need to be calculate and input by hand which seems too hard, maybe there is a tool I just need to crop where the object is in image?

4.if the object is not a square in image, how does YOLO know which part are object?  How to avoid it train background as object?

do I have to remove all background and fill it as black, only keep the object in image?

5.is the output always a box?  can  I train and get output as mask?  if  I detect as mask, will it slower then box because it seems to be more information?

6.to get a good result, how many training image and test image should I make?

I know it's just some noob question in CV,  however I really want to know this without spending weeks in training and find out  answer myself , an answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_manual_image_annotation_tools

You should be able to get output of corners coordinates by using some image annotation tool.

4.

With enough images with different background for training, supposedly the model should be able to ignore background. A black background is still a background. I guess that's a kind of data augmentation, so it might help reduce overfitting.

5.

If it does not support mask out-of-the-box, maybe you want to do background-subtraction as an extra step to process the output.

Answer (score 0):

1) In my opinion, GTX 1050Ti is not enough to test YOLO v3. Because, the model size (i.e. the number of layers) of the YOLO v3 becomes extremely large compared with the previous versions. The number of classes will be not matter in this case. If you want fast test computing speed, you should upgrade your GPU like 1070Ti.

2) Whatever the size of input images, it will be resized into the pre-defined size, which is depicted as cfg file, by force, so you don't need to resize the input image.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think it may affect the speed a bit in because as you use less classes you get less convolutional filters before each YOLO layer (you set it up in the .cfg file), but it's not likely gonna be an 80x speed up
2) Maybe? I mean, YOLO's gonna resize them when training and then testing, so maybe if you really want to you could, but high res images usually work better, in my experience.
3)I like the OpenLabelling (you can just Google it and it's on GitHub)
4) You may wanna give YOLO negative images that have nothing in them to prevent them picking up on a background, where there's nothing there
5)YOLO doesn't do masks
6)About 1k per class is what probably will work, you can get by with 500 but the rule of thumb is that the more, the better)

If you're interested, I've put out the whole series on YOLO on YouTube, so you may wanna check it out: https://youtu.be/TP67icLSt1Y